# Updated Code of Conduct banner messing up site design

Tags: bug

The banner at the top of the page that says

> Join us in  building a kind, collaborative learning community via our updated [Code of Conduct »](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Is making the `unanswered` and `ask question` links disappear in Firefox 61.0.1 and Chrome (don't remember what version -- I mostly use FF).

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Broken page]

Happens on the main site and on Meta.

Comment: Repro on Chrome 68 (latest stable on Windows)

Comment: [Similar problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313748/295232) have been spotted on Graphic Design and Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I just made a screenshot to come here and report the same thing!

Comment: I've been on vacation for 2 weeks, everything looks fine in the mobile app. Just got back to my computer to see the layout messed up as described above. But when I [enabled the new site theme](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5756/photography-new-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing), the new layout looks fine. So... out with the old, I guess?