# Photography new site theme is ready for testing

Tags: discussion, design, themes

We have enabled the new site theme for testing on your site.

### How do I enable it?

[Click here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences) and check the "Beta test new themes". This will turn on the new theme for any site, including this one, that has a theme ready for testing. *[more info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314542/opt-in-to-beta-testing-new-themes)*

### What type of feedback do we need?

**Bugs related to your sites theme:** Please help us look for issues/bugs related to the theme design and how we have mapped the old theme to the new. This needs to be done within the [limits of the new unified theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes). I will post on each site when the theme is ready for testing and bugs should be posted as answers to that post with the details (including images please!).

**General concerns about left nav or theming:** If you have concerns or issues regarding the left nav or the overall approach we are taking to theming, then [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) is the right place for feedback.

### What new theme?

If you're like, "What the heck are you talking about?", then you should read the Meta Stack Exchange post entitled [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes)  (and maybe the posts it links to for the full background).

Answer (score 4):

Note: this is a global problem, so I've posted it at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315140/154627

---

### On mobile, username and picture of editors shown before authors, making it easy to assume wrong author if you don't look closely

Example:

[image]

If you just skim and don't carefully look for "edited" or "answered", it's easy to assume that the first person listed is the one primarily associated with the answer. This should probably go the other way around.

Comment: Good eye! This is subtle. If the first avatar picture & profile link is always the author, then it will always be in the same place with respect to the "share edit flag" links, whether or not a post has even been edited.

Answer (score 3):

## The right bar is bumped to the bottom, but doesn't change width

A centered div like this doesn't look good.  Also, it would be nice to be able to have our Photo of the Week on top instead of getting bumped to the bottom.

[image]

Comment: We are working out how we can handle the right side bar content better when the window narrows. Some things will get integrated into the main content area. For example, on sites with ads, the ads will get inlined below the question. Another example is site disclaimers (eg. judaism.se) which will be inlined at the top of the content area. We could potentially do the same for the Photo of the Week, but I'm not 100% sure we should.

Comment: Worthy of a meta question?  Or is that a SE inc decision?

Answer (score 1):

## Visual Comparison

(for those of us who didn't want to enable it ourselves yet)

### Main page

#### Full Width

New:

[image: new full width]
[Old full width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXknf.png)

#### Tablet View

New:

[image: new tablet view]
[Old tablet view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3sm5.png)
Note the cropped sidebar in the old, versus bumped to bottom of page on new (not shown).

#### Smaller Tablet View

New:

[image: new sm tab view]
[Old small tablet view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75uir.png)

#### Phone Size

New:

[image: New phone Size]
[Old phone size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsQro.png)

Comment: You might want to add screenshots with the left nav hidden pref turned on to show the full range.

Comment: Meh, it's exactly the same, with a few extra pixels of room on the left side.  I think it's easy enough to imagine.  If you'd like to add anything though, I changed it to a community wiki so feel free to.

Answer (score 1):

> Bugs related to your sites theme: Please help us look for issues/bugs related to the theme design and how we have mapped the old theme to the new. This needs to be done within the limits of the new unified theme. I will post on each site when the theme is ready for testing and bugs should be posted as answers to that post with the details (including images please!).

It was [requested](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5721/37074) and marked [[status-completed] on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312491/282094) that the Moderators would get a text area. There was [some further discussion](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5714/new-photography-site-theme-coming-soon/5721#comment11683_5721) that sites getting the [Bentley](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley) (and not the [Yugo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zastava_Koral)) treatment, like Mi Yodeya and Photography, in addition to a couple of lines of text could insert a few links.

Is it missing?, since **there doesn't seem to be a blank spot** for it **or** is there a Tab on the Moderator's controls that they need to visit and manually reinstall their message? Thanks.

Before Image:

[image: Before]

After Image:

[image: After]

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
Also, a bite is taken out of our hamburger - everything needs to shift left a bit.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong status tagging on the request regarding the mod message. I've set that to [meta-tag:status-declined]. We will be supporting a per-site disclaimer (ala Judaism or Health) but we won't support a more general mod message at this time. If mods across the network think this is a thing we need to support we can consider a feature request. Based on the information I have, the way you're creating that message wasn't really how that functionality was designed to be used (most mods can't edit the HTML).

Comment: Thanks. No problem. I'm not a moderator. I don't know how it would be different from editing the FAQ and having the text appear in a frame within a CSS block but I'm not writing the code. :) With the zero UpVotes this has received it's apparently of no concern on this end. Thanks for clarifying this, and looking for my [hamburglar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w8sZ.jpg).

Comment: @JoeFriend - The Hamburger is **repaired**. With the other point **status-declined** I believe that this answer is fully resolved. Thx.